# Android: JUnit test: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Intent was null

Tags: android

I wrote a simple Android App containing 2 activities:
1) Login.java- which takes in a username and password and then directs the user to another activity-DisplayMessageActivity.java

2) DisplayMessageActivity.java- the activity that appears on the second screen after the user is re-directed

Following which, I wrote a simple test MainActivityUnitTest.java to test whether the correct intent is triggered via the getStartedActivityIntent() method

I manually tested it on an Android phone and it works, however, when i run MainActivityUnitTest.java as a JUnit test it revealed :
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Intent was null

at this line:

```
assertNotNull("Intent was null", triggeredIntent);
```

MainActivityUnitTest.java

```
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends
android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<Login> {

private int buttonId;
private Login activity;

public MainActivityUnitTest() {
 super(Login.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
 super.setUp();
 Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
    Login.class);
 startActivity(intent, null, null);
 activity = getActivity();
}


public void testLayout(){
    //buttonId = com.example.myfirstapp2.MainActivity.R.id.button1;
    //assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));

    Button view = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "Login", view.getText());

 }

 public void testIntentTriggerViaOnClick() {

  Button view = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
  assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", view);

  view.performClick();
  Intent triggeredIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();
  assertNotNull("Intent was null", triggeredIntent);

  String data = triggeredIntent.getExtras().getString("URL");

    assertEquals("Incorrect data passed via the intent",
        "1http://www.vogella.com", data);
    }



     }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your Login activity is under test.

Does these activity call startactivity before you call getStartedActivityIntent?

> public Intent getStartedActivityIntent ()
>
> Added in API level 1 This method will return the launch intent if your
>   Activity under test calls startActivity(Intent) or
>   startActivityForResult(Intent, int).
>
> Returns The Intent provided in the start call, or null if no start
>   call was made.

Comment: Yes it does
    view.performClick();
   Intent triggeredIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();

Comment: However, the Login activity calls the startactivity


inside
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

block

as I am parsing a web service